avrdude OS error: cannot set attributes for port /dev/ttyS0: inappropriate ioctl for device
avrdude fails to connect to programmer, my OS is linux mint 22 on 64bit intel laptop.
when running this command:
sudo avrdude -c stk500

i get this error:
avrdude OS error: cannot set attributes for port /dev/ttyS0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
avrdude error: unable to open programmer stk500 on port /dev/ttyS0


i figured this out, just need to add this option to avrdude command:
-P /dev/ttyUSB0

this is the full command:
avr-gcc -O -Wall -mmcu=attiny24a demo.c -o demo.out

avr-objcopy -O ihex demo.out demo.hex

sudo avrdude -v -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -B 125kHz -p ATtiny24A -c stk500 -e -U flash:w:demo.hex

this code compiles c code into .hex file and flashes the program into avr microcontroller using my stk500 programmer board.
